# MySQL - COUNT scatter classified by multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_results` (
`id` int AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date_time` datetime,
`altpn` varchar(60),
`vsp` decimal(10,4),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

VALUES
(null, 2016-07-22 13:30:01, pn1, 14.55),
(null, 2016-07-22 13:30:02, pn1, 14.45),
(null, 2016-07-22 13:30:03, pn1, 14.55),
(null, 2016-07-22 13:30:04, pn2, 14.45),
(null, 2016-07-22 13:30:05, pn2, 14.65),
(null, 2016-07-22 13:30:06, pn2, 14.45);
```

And i need result like this:

```
vsp - altpn - COUNT
14.45 - pn1 - 1
14.45 - pn2 - 2
14.55 - pn1 - 2
14.55 - pn2 - 0
14.65 - pn1 - 0
14.65 - pn2 - 1
```

It can also be altpn - vsp - COUNT, it does not matter. But every vsp value must contain all pns, which are in table. Even that with zero value.

Is this even possible to do? I can do normal SQL like:

```
SELECT   test_results.vsp, 
         test_results.altpn, 
         COUNT(*) 
FROM     test_results 
GROUP BY test_results.vsp, 
         test_results.altpn
```

and re-compute this result in php to table what i need (For chart), but it will by easier do it in SQL.

Comment: on a casual inspection, it looks like that sql you submitted would give the desired results ... what exactly are you asking? Is the question about issuing that query in PHP and displaying it in a chart on the web?

Comment: @JoelMartinez - it'll drop the 0's

Comment: @fbituco - You'll want to make a list of all vsp/altpn that you want to include and left join to your count query (make it a subquery).  Do you have logic as to which rows to include?  How do you know the 14.65/pn1 exists and has a count of 0 while 14.75/pn1 doesn't exist?

Comment: Hi. I don't know. But i know that 14.65 exists (DISTINCT test_results.vsp) and pn1 exists (DISTINCT test_results.altpn). So I must check all vsp values vs all pns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.  You'll want to assemble together a list of all the unique vsp/altpn and then left join that to a count subquery.  I'm going to use a crossjoin of distinct values of vps to the distinct values of altpn to create that list for you...you might want to use business logic if there is something that determines when a vsp/altpn combination is valid in your results.

```
select a.vsp, a.altpn, ifnull(counts.totalcount,0)
from (select vsp.vsp, altpn.altpn
      from (select vsp 
            from test_results 
            group by vsp)vsp 
      join 
           (select altpn 
            from test_results 
            group by altpn)altpn 
      on 1=1) a
left join
           (SELECT test_results.vsp, test_results.altpn, COUNT(*) as totalcount
            FROM test_results 
            GROUP BY test_results.vsp, test_results.altpn) counts
on a.vsp = counts.vsp and a.altpn = counts.altpn
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT d.*,
       c.*,
  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM test_results e
   WHERE e.altpn=d.idaltpn
     AND e.vsp=c.idvsp)
FROM
  (SELECT distinct(a.altpn) idaltpn
   FROM test_results a) d,

  (SELECT distinct(a.vsp) idvsp
   FROM test_results a) c
```

Comment: Hi. I'm not able make this code working. It is showing error near "d,". Replacing by "d JOIN" does not help.